# Why does the Blender 2.9 download for linux install 2.79b

Tags: error, linux

so I am trying to install Blender on a chromebook through the linux terminal and by through trial and error,finally got blender working but its running on version 2.79b even though i used the latest download link for linux on the official blender website.

Comment: I don't know what link you've used, but the [download page](https://www.blender.org/download/) links the correct files. All past releases of Blender can be accessed on [this page](https://download.blender.org/release/).

Comment: Only you know where you downloaded and uncompressed the blender folder. Note that it is possible to have multiple versions of blender on the same computer. If that is the case just make sure that you are opening the blender program from the correct folder.